# making python itertools work on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to learn python itertools (love it so far!), but I am struck with a problem. I have the following two lists:

```
a=["http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287", "http://www.hjuk.com/kashjh716", "http://www.psudjg.com/9279jshkoh", "http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287",  "http://www.xyz.com/9289jhjbg"]
data=["k","some small string here", "so med string here", "some string here","l"]
tempstring="http://www.xyz.com"
```

Initially, what I wanted was to remove data[i] for all strings which are below a certain length, and subsequently delete the corresponding entries in a. For this, I used something along the lines of:

```
iselectors = [x is not len(str(x))>1 for x in data]
data=list(itertools.compress(data, iselectors))
a=list(itertools.compress(a, selectors))
```

..which works well. Now, I need to add another condition to my iselectors, which states that only when "tempstring is in a[i]" and len(str(x))>1..

So, I have tried something like:

```
iselectors = [tempstring in a and x is not len(str(x))>1 for x in data]
```

...but I am not sure this is right, since I do not think I am iterating over the entire a when I use "tempstring in a"

Any guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to work it through:

```
>>> pprint(zip(data, a))
[('k', 'http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287'),
 ('some small string here', 'http://www.hjuk.com/kashjh716'),
 ('so med string here', 'http://www.psudjg.com/9279jshkoh'),
 ('some string here', 'http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287'),
 ('l', 'http://www.xyz.com/9289jhjbg')]

>>> [ (av, dv) for av, dv in zip(a, data) if len(av) > 1 and tempstring in av]
[('http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287', 'k'), ('http://www.xyz.com/jhuh7287', 'some string here'), ('http://www.xyz.com/9289jhjbg', 'l')]
```

So with a bit of refactoring:

```
selectors = (tempstring in dv for av, dv in izip(a, data) if len(av) > 1)
```

And since @mgilson deleted his answer with a key point - which I hope the OP has taken on board, I'm going to re-post his wording to this answer:

> Also, `is` is used to compare object identities. While this check works
>   for small integers in Cpython (1 is len(str(1))), it's not guaranteed
>   to work with other python implementations (nor is it guaranteed to
>   work in Cpython in the future). I think you just want len(str(x))>1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I got it now!

Comment: @johnj welcome - don't forget to heed mgilson's warning about the use of `is` - you don't want to be using it for this case

Comment: for some stupid reason, I like using the keyword "is". Why is it that it will not work on future Cpython implementations? Is there a reference for this? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @JohnJ I don't know of any off-hand (but I'm sure you can google it), but it's just an implementation issue that it works in CPython... Generally, the spec. of `is` says that it will return True if the objects are the same, it's just a fluke that sometimes that occurs when the value of the object is the same... Don't worry about it, and use it for what it's meant for - otherwise use `==`

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to iterate over both at the same time

```
iselectors = [len(str(x))>1 and tempstring in y for x,y in zip(data,a)]
```